# in zurb foundation, can i insert one form inside "reveal" popup?

Tags: ajax, forms, zurb-foundation

and how can I trasmit data between popup and page that have called popup?
I would like to do a ajax form for user registration inside popup "reveal" in zurb foundation. 
Do you think is possible?

Answer (score 6):

This answer might be a little late, but you can absolutely put a form into the reveal popup.  For instance, if you wanted a login dialog to show up when they click a login button:

At the bottom of your HTML (after all the rows), create the content for the popup:

```
<div id="login-modal" class="reveal-modal" style="width: 400px; background: black; color: white;">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form id="login-form" class="six">
        <div class="row">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" />
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
             <div class="right" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                 <button type="reset" class="button radius alert">Reset</button>
                 <button type="submit" class="button radius">Login</button>
             </div>
         </div>
     </form>
     <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Then you can display it using one of their methods.  The new foundation 3.0 let you display it super easy like:

```
<a href="#" 
   data-reveal-id="login-modal" 
   data-animation="fadeAndPop" 
   data-animationspeed="300" 
   data-closeonbackgroundclick="true" 
   data-dismissmodalclass="close-reveal-modal">Login</a>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

try this in app.js.
Then use reveal class on any anchor

```
  $('a.reveal').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var $div = $('<div>').addClass('reveal-modal').appendTo('body'),
        $this = $(this);
        $div.empty().html('<p align="center"><img src="application/public/loading.gif" /></p>').append('<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>').reveal();

          $.get($this.attr('href'), function(data) {
            return $div.empty().html(data).append('<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>').reveal();
          });
    });
```